# automatically resize type tool box - shortcut

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I was some time without using photoshop regularly and i forgot this shortcut. How adapt the size of the type tool box to the dimension of the text ?

Obviously this can be done with the mouse, but i am interesting in the shortcut.

Comment: For some reason I have never seen this as much of an issue in photoshop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, I don't think there's a keyboard shortcut for this. However, if you set a keyboard shortcut for `Change Text Shape Type`, you can hit it twice, and it will *sorta* do what you want—by changing the type object to a point text and then converting it back to paragraph text.

I've tested this, and it works for the vertical size. But it generally leaves a lot of extra room on the non-flushed / ragged side. It also doesn't work when you have non-zero margins set.

After a little experimenting, it seems that the extra space added to the non-aligned side is a lot smaller when you use larger font sizes. And for some reason, this remains true even if you scale down the text area. So starting with a larger version of the text object and scaling it down is a workaround.

Comment: That's one wild and wooly workaround! If I still set area type in Photoshop I might give it a whirl, just for grins, but as you point out it's a very blunt instrument. Come to think of it, so is Photoshop when you're talking about type. :)

Comment: I remember that have a shortcut for that in indesign. My bad. Anyway, a shortcut would be great for me in photoshop :)

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of such a shortcut.

You can resize the type via Command/Ctrl - Shift - < or Command/Ctrl - Shift - >

But only the mouse will resize a text area.